# Unexpected result coming from JSON parser

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON object. For example, there is a part like this in my JSON object :

> "Addition":""

When I try to parse this in JSON and log the result from Logcat like this :

```
        if(myobj.has("Addition"))
        {
            myMaterial.Addition=myobj.getString("Addition");
            Log.d("myobj.getString("Addition")", myobj.getString("Addition"));
        }
        else
        {
            myMaterial.Addition= null;
        }
```

The result of the Log is this :

> D/myobj.getString("Addition")﹕ [ 07-15 09:36:49.987  1221: 1440
>   V/WindowManager ]

Why am I getting this result instead of empty string? How can I get an empty string for this case? Thanks.

Comment: Add a json which you  are parsing

Comment: tbh the ouput looks good. `[ 07-15 09:36:49.987 1221: 1440 V/WindowManager ]` seems something from android, but strictly related to your app

Comment: @Blackbelt shouldn't I get an empty string?

Comment: it is probably an empty string and logcat is messing with you

Comment: Can you try 

`Log.d("myobj.getString(\"Addition\")", myobj.getString("Addition"));` ?

Comment: Can you Log it as " Log.d("myobj.getString("Addition")", ":-->" + myobj.getString("Addition"));

Comment: @m0rpheu5 I get this : `:-->` only on the right side.

Comment: @jason Is "myobj" a JSONObject or JSONArray ?? Please do check the type of "Addition".

Comment: @m0rpheu5 it is a JSONObject inside a JSONArray. Addition is definitely a string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `optString(key, defaultValue)` instead of `getString`. Provide an empty string as the default value - in this case you can also drop the `has(..)` check.